# Haproxy appears do be issuing the wrong certificate

Tags: ssl, haproxy, ssl-certificate-errors, bitbucket

I am trying to secure a domain with haproxy. When I load the URL: bitbucket.kl.company.com, I get the error:

```
bitbucket.kl.company.com uses an invalid security certificate.

This certificate is only valid for the following names:
*.company.com, company.com, bitbucket-mirror.company.com

Error Code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN
```

Now if I go onto the server and do the following:

```
 openssl x509 -text -noout -in /etc/haproxy/certs/cert.pem | grep DNS
                DNS:*.company.com, DNS:company.com, DNS:bitbucket.kl.company.com
```

I contacted Digicert who issue the certificates, and they said the server was issuing the wrong certificate.

In my haproxy.cfg I have:

```
frontend bitbucket_http_frontend
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/cert.pem ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
    redirect scheme https code 301 if !{ ssl_fc }
    default_backend bitbucket_http_backend
```

This *appears* to be what is happening...

haproxy is issuing other certificates from within `/etc/haproxy/certs`

I didn't expect or ask it to do that, but that is the only conclusion that makes sense, unless there is a default location that it looks in first.

Comment: You could also have made an error when you built cert.pem.  `openssl x509` only reads the *first* cert in the file.  Carve that file into individual certificates and examine each one individually.

Comment: This was helpful thank you, it wasnt the reason why it didn't work nut led me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to a stale haproxy process which had been started without 'systemctl', and had been running for 3 months.  It was issuing certificates for a long since deleted pem file.

I thought there would have been a port clash or something but there was not. haproxy did not complain.

Comment: When I found this answer, I realized there were many ways to confirm this. The `STARTTIME` column in `htop` for the main process is the same before the reload and after it. But at that point it's enough to just move all of the certificates to a different folder and see them still being issued after reload.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to stop haproxy service :

```
sudo service haproxy stop
```

after that, kill all processes related to HAProxy :

```
ps aux | grep haproxy
user_1     3648060  0.0  0.0  ...
user_root  3680653  0.0  0.0  ...
```

kill all processes:

```
kill -9 <process id>
kill -9 3648060
kill -9 3680653
```

finally, restart HAProxy service and watch logs :

```
sudo service haproxy start
tail -f /var/log/haproxy.log
```